# Why was this answer made into a "Community Wiki"?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

There was this question just a few minutes ago:

[PHP redirect with appended GET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15029289/1456376)

It received an answer from [Kolink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) which is now a Community Wiki answer.

When I read "[What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/190341)" it states:

> One of the goals of the website is to be a continually evolving source of good information. Community Wiki posts help enhance the wiki aspect of the site.

Regarding the question which is pretty easy to solve and basically just a typo, is this state for the answer not a little exaggerative?

Comment: It's the author who made it community wiki. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15029355/revisions

Comment: OK, but why? I always thought that CW is only for answer/questions that are really good and could help a lot of people in the future. This problem seems to be very localized.

Comment: I assume the author doesn't want to take the credit for an answer based on the comments of others. But that's a mere guess.

Comment: That's also what I figured. I always thought that there's a little more magic behind CW. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kolink himself choose to make it a CW answer, see the [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15029355/revisions).

> Post Made Community Wiki by [Kolink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink)

My guess is that he didn't feel he deserved to get reputation for such an obvious answer. You'll have to ask him himself for the exact reasons.

Comment: Your last sentence is what I thought too. But just in case: Is it a good practice to turn answers like that into CW?

Comment: @insertusernamehere: That is up to the author.

Comment: Alright, than I learned something about CW today. :) Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15029355/revisions), you'll see the author of the answer made it Community Wiki. This is an option whenever posting an answer.

> Post Made Community Wiki by [Kolink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink)